# Can you reload init.vim in-place in a way that gets rid of old keybindings?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, init

Is it possible to reload `init.vim` without quitting Vim (Neovim in my particular case, but I don't think it should be different)?

All the answers to this question that I've found here just say to re-source `init.vim`, however that doesn't seem to get rid of keybidings, functions, etc... that are already loaded.

I recently got rid of a plugin from my Neovim setup that had a conflicting keybinding, only to find that even though I had:

1. modified and saved my config
2. deleted the plugin directory
3. and re-sourced my config

...the keybinding conflict was still there, with the additional failure that the called function couldn't be located.

Comment: depending on the mapping just `:unmap` should do it?

Answer (score 1):

thanks to [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt) in the comments for pointing me down the right path. `:help unmap` opens right above `:help mapclear`, which does what I need. My process is now:

1. modify & save config
2. delete plugin directory
3. `:mapclear` (kills ALL keybindings)
4. `:so ~/.config/nvim/init.vim`

`:unmap` will also work, if you happen to know ALL of the keybindings set by the deleted plugin. I'm not so careful or knowledgeable about the plugins I use...

Comment: Note that in general sourcing your vimrc file doesn’t reload `plugin/*.vim` files, so that may prevent some mappings from being created or other code from executing.

Comment: Good point. I copped the idea of putting each plugins vim-plug line and configuration code in individual `plugin/*.vim` files from a [youtube video by jess archer](https://youtu.be/434tljD-5C8?t=779), so my `init.vim` sources all those files explicitly. it's made for a much cleaner [`init.vim`](https://github.com/jessarcher/dotfiles/commit/41f389c5da6b83d3c67a28b55b7d5a85cfd2ffbc?diff=unified) than my previous monstrosity, so credit to her.

Comment: Any file in `plugin` directories on the `runtimepath` is executed automatically… `:source`ing or `:runtime`ing them without a guard means they are run twice.

Comment: @rreagan3 I see how it's tempting to explicitly load plugins, however you'd probably better make use of vim's mecanism to do that, as stated by DBK.